# Alterar template de classes no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, template

Existe forma de configurar o Visual Studio para criar as classes com o `public`?

Ao criar uma classe por template, seja pelo menu *dropdown* do mouse sobre um nome de classe ainda não existente, ou por adicionar uma classe em um projeto, elas são criadas sem o `public`.

Exemplo:

```
class QualquerCoisa
{
}
```

Existe forma de fazer com que seja criado com o public?, assim:

```
public class QualquerCoisa
{
}
```

Como?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Procura este arquivo, é ele que você quer mudar:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

Acho que ficaria algo assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Template.cs).

Para usar com outras versões do VS basta mudar a versão no caminho do arquivo. Só lembrando que do Visual Studio 2010 para trás o arquivo está compactado em formato `zip`. É pouco provável que mude fundamentalmente na versões futuros como o novo [Visual Studio 2015](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou a [edição Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é gratuito para quase todo mundo. Além do .NET passar ter [licença MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).