# Visual studio abre código já existente quando clico em NOVO projeto?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Comecei a aprender C# e estou usando o Visual Studio. 
criei meu programa básico "hello world", salvei o projeto. Até ai tudo bem, mas quando vou abrir um projeto NOVO, para poder criar um novo código, ele puxa o código desse meu primeiro programinha.

Claro que eu posso apagar esse código e digitar o novo, mas o projeto vem sem todas as `using` (o projeto vem só com a `using.system`).

[image: Quando clico em arquivo > Novo projeto, é isso que aparece, ao invés de aparecer um projeto NOVO!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, ele tem gabaritos (*templates*) com um início bem básico de código que provavelmente você vai precisar de acordo com o tipo de projeto escolhido. Assim você não precisa digitar o que vai precisar de qualquer jeito. Alguns tipos de projetos chegam criar vários arquivos e até mesmo códigos que podemos classificar como "complexos" para um início. Não é seu primeiro programa, é o gabarito.

É possível inclusive [criar seus próprios gabaritos ou modificar os existentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40271/101).

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela resposta, esclareceu minha dúvida. Como estou aprendendo sozinho, tenho estas dúvidas "idiotas". Abrçs!

Comment: @HenriqueScharfPisa Nenhuma dúvida é idiota se ela é legítima. Veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado aqui ;)